# Access Java terminal from C++ with JNA

Tags: java, c++, console, jna

I'm trying to use a [`getch()` alternative](https://repl.it/@PasAdam/Alternative-to-getch-in-conioh) in C++ I found online in my Java program, so I'm using JNA to provide native access for Java. However, when I call the method using JNA it blocks indefinitely, which makes me think that it doesn't have access to the current console. What's more, when I tried to log to console from `std::cout` or take input from `std::cin` with JNA, I got an invalid memory access error.

What I want to know is: Is it possible to set the console that the C++ program will use, so that it can log to and get input from the console the Java program uses? Sorry if that's a little vague- I don't know how else to phrase it...

interface:

```java
import com.sun.jna.Library;

interface NativeLib extends Library {
    int getch();
}
```

main:

```java
import com.sun.jna.Native;
...
NativeLib lib = (NativeLib) Native.loadLibrary("getchar", NativeLib.class);
lib.getch();
```

Comment: JNA can't read C++ functions unless they are exported.  Why are you not simply using Java functions to read stdin/write stdout?

Comment: I need to have access to C++ console functions such as `getch()`. However, `getch()` doesn't work as it doesn't have access to the console Java is using. I need `getch()` like capabilities as I need to be able to take character input without the user having to press enter. I've searched extensively, but C/C++ seem to be the only place really that can take char input before enter is pressed.